# Spring Boot (jdk11) maven web app cannot run in payara/server-full:5.2022.2-jdk11 docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, payara

I have been trying for three days to deploy a `Spring` application (jdk/jre 11) with `IntelliJ` on a dockerized `Payara` application server without success, since my requests are getting error 404 not found. So I guessed it was my application's fault to finally find out after hours of testing that no Spring application can run without this error.

Whether it is a simple rest api:

```
@RestController("/")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("index")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testValidationService() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("it works", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

or it is a simple html page with a simple controller to redirect to it, I get error 404. It's really hard to believe that something so simple can not work.

Of course all of the above are working on localhosted `Payara` and of course I have tried all the solutions suggested in other threads without success. Please note that admin panel of dockerized `Payara` shows that the deployment is successful so the app is running. Please also note that other `Java` 11 applications (without `Spring` framework) are working fine) So the question is one and very simple:

**How can I deploy a simple hello world spring application (jdk 11) (war packaging) (without 404 errors) in this version of dockerized payara [payara/server-full:5.2022.2-jdk11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/server-full/payara/server-full/5.2022.2-jdk11/images/sha256-e061c9bc4e8ef0ad332e86dbe70cf61757f680f7d3e24e0964d42693a069bce6)?**

You can easily reproduce my issue using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM payara/server-full:5.2022.2-jdk11
EXPOSE 4848 8080 8181 9009
COPY target/springapp.war $DEPLOY_DIR
```

After built you can run it using the following command:

```
docker run --publish 8080:8080 --publish 4848:4848 [image_name]
```

**EDIT**

**Logs after @dekkard's suggestions:**

**from the container:**

```
[Entrypoint] running /opt/payara/scripts/init_1_generate_deploy_commands.sh
Adding deployment target /opt/payara/deployments/springapp.war to post boot commands

[Entrypoint] ignoring /opt/payara/scripts/init.d/*

Executing Payara Server with the following command line:
/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca-amd64/bin/java
-cp
/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jrt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.logging/java.util.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:+UseContainerSupport
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0
-Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
-Xss512k
-server
-javaagent:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.security.policy=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER=org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Djdbc.drivers=org.h2.Driver
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.force-selector-spin-detection=true
-Djava.library.path=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-prebootcommandfile
/opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
-upgrade
false
-read-stdin
true
-postbootcommandfile
/opt/payara/config/post-boot-commands-final.asadmin
-domainname
domain1
-domaindir
/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--user,,,admin,,,--passwordfile,,,/opt/payara/passwordFile,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--extraterse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,--autoname=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain
-watchdog
false

Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
May 30, 2022 8:36:06 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@7a378326 in service registry.
Reading in commandments from /opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
[#|2022-05-30T20:36:11.341+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2022.2|javax.enterprise.logging|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1653942971189;_TimeMillis=1653942971341;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-LOGGING-00009;|
  Running Payara Version: Payara Server  5.2022.2 #badassfish (build 306)|#]

[#|2022-05-30T20:36:11.350+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2022.2|javax.enterprise.logging|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1653942971189;_TimeMillis=1653942971350;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-LOGGING-00010;|
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter|#]

[#|2022-05-30T20:36:11.816+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2022.2|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1653942971199;_TimeMillis=1653942971816;_LevelValue=800;|
  Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]

[#|2022-05-30T20:36:14.412+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2022.2|fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1653942971189;_TimeMillis=1653942974412;_LevelValue=800;|
  Hazelcast Instance Bound to JNDI at payara/Hazelcast|#]

[#|2022-05-30T20:36:14.413+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2022.2|fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1653942971189;_TimeMillis=1653942974413;_LevelValue=800;|
  JSR107 Caching Provider Bound to JNDI at payara/CachingProvider|#]
```

**from payara:**

```
[2022-05-30T20:36:06.293+0000] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] [javax.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1653942966293] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca-amd64/bin/java
-cp
/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jrt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.logging/java.util.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:+UseContainerSupport
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0
-Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
-Xss512k
-server
-javaagent:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.security.policy=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER=org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Djdbc.drivers=org.h2.Driver
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.force-selector-spin-detection=true
-Djava.library.path=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-prebootcommandfile
/opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
-upgrade
false
-read-stdin
true
-postbootcommandfile
/opt/payara/config/post-boot-commands-final.asadmin
-domainname
domain1
-domaindir
/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--user,,,admin,,,--passwordfile,,,/opt/payara/passwordFile,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--extraterse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,--autoname=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain
-watchdog
false]]
```

**proof of successful deployment:**

[image: payara]

Comment: so you could run and access that endpoint locally (when ran from Gradle / IntelliJ ), right?
are you able to pull some logs from Payara and share them with us?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I use Maven and not Gradle (I should have mentioned it). The logs of the docker container show absolutely nothing when I get the 404 error and the same happens in the logs of the dockerized payara. I updated the original post to see them as confirmation. I hope you can help.

Comment: Have you taken into consideration the fact payara appends the .war name to the URL? so it should be something like host:port/WAR_NAME/index?

Comment: Yes I took it into account because it works the same way on localhost, but to be sure I also copied the context root (war name) from the Payara's admin panel.

Comment: The logs from the dockerized Payara don't event show the deployment process of your application. Are you sure it's deployed at all? Are there any errors appearing during this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The logs of the docker container indicate that the deployment was successful. I believe they have configured it such that you can access it directly from your IDE rather than having to seek for logs via the Payara's admin panel. However, I enter each time and check the admin panel to see if the application has been deployed, and I even copy the context root to ensure that I access the right url. Please keep in mind that when I deploy other applications that do not use the spring framework, everything works fine.

Comment: Ok, disregard the last comment, I see the app context root is `/springapp`. What's the URL of the requests you tried and got 404 for?

Comment: The url I tried was this: http://localhost:8080/springapp/index

Comment: Try connecting to your running payara container with something like `docker exec -it <container name> bash` and verify your app endpoints with `asadmin list-rest-endpoints springapp` command (to make sure the app is actually named "springapp" you can run `asadmin list-applications`).  I'd also suggest enabling debug logging level in your application.properties (`logging.level.root=debug`) to see if any request comes through to your application.

Comment: @dekkard I followed all your instructions and updated the logs in the original post (after the word "EDIT"). Unfortunately I do not see any problem, I hope you can see something more.